# How to make a survey taking bot?

Tags: javascript, python, php, html

I work in Market Research and one of the things we always have to check for in our data is the presence of Bots that've completed the survey rather than a real human being.

There's several metrics we use for that and we're fairly sure we catch the most of them.

I've just moved to a new company and the research platform doesn't have the option to generate "dummy data", a first for me in nearly two decades of doing this and I find it immensely useful to cram a few hundred fake completes through to check all my scripting is in order.

So, I figured I might try to take one of the blight's of my occupation and put it to some good use.

However, a bit of googling hasn't yielded much in a way of assistance (expect one app that my antivirus *really* didn't like) - I figure if it's easy enough to implement for some chumps wanting to make the odd dollar, I should be able to get my head around it surely?

I'm not a programmer, I know some scripting (JS / PHP and what not) and have poked around Python on occasion. Would that be my best starting place? All it needs to do is randomly select an element on a page and then hit the next button (which has a standard div ID and javascript function).

Any help would be greatly appreciated on where to start building what will be an awesome little time save (as well as ass saver if it helps debug my surveys!).

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically control webpage interactions by using a **headless browser**.

[Headless browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) are most often used for:

- Scraping websites for data.
- Automating interaction of web.
- Test automation in modern web applications.
- Taking screenshots of web pages.

[Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) is a popular [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) library that offers control of Chrome programmatically. Puppeteer is extensively documented and there are a multitude of videos online of how to use Puppeteer.

Here's a sample of the code necessary to take a screenshot of a page for instance:

```js
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  var page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds exactly like what I need!